# DM101 Smart Watch Android Application - Issue with application not filling the screen

Tags: android-studio, wear-os, wearables

When I deploy the application to the device for testing, the application does not fill the screen.
FYI: the DM101 SmartWatch does not support wear OS, it uses Android 7.1.1 (API 25)

if you want to see what it looks like
[link to watch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08P5R7GST)

I am using Android Studio and setup the Manifest to be compatible with the Device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appnft">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!--    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />-->

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
        >
<!--       <uses-library-->
<!--            android:name="com.android." "com.google.android.wearable"-->
<!--            android:required="false" />-->

<!--        <meta-data-->
<!--            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"-->
<!--            android:value="true" />-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.max_aspect"
            android:value="2"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

issue visual

[picture of the actual issue on watch with app running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NlHI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I Found the answer after researching for almost a week.
In part it was embedded my question; the DM101 does not support wear OS and because of this I should have started a new android studio project with target a mobile application.

My first mistake was to try adapting the wear OS template manifest.

Second: on the DM101 Smart Watch under developer options, there is the ability to allow third party applications to go full screen; which did not work when using the adapted wear OS Manifest template.